# Is there a way to refer to a long host name and use that reference to log into mysql?

Tags: mysql, command-line

In order to log into MySQL in the command line, I have to do the usual to log in:

`mysql -u [username] -h [host name] -p`

But my host name is very long, so I'm constantly having to copy it from a document and paste it in the field. Is there a way I can save it to some sort of variable and then use that variable in the host name field? This would save me some time. I've looked but can't find anything about this. Maybe it's not possible, but if it is, I would appreciate if someone can show me how to do this. Also, I am using Windows if that's helpful.

Comment: Is it always the same hostname? Put it into your `.my.cnf` file.

Comment: @Barmar no it's not. I have two different ones.

Comment: You could simply use an environment variable, like `set abc=verylongname` ? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @fvu I've never messed with environment variables so you'll need to go into detail on how to do it. And if environment variables is suitable for that parameter, then sure that would be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use environment variables, either set permanently via control panel --> system, or ad hoc (meaning that their lifetime is the one of the command line window), on the command line, like this:

```
set h1=verververylongname.thaticannotrembereasily.com
```

and then

```
mysql -u [username] -h %h1% -p
```

You can make one variable per host to contact obviously

Comment: I tried this and I got an error: `c:\xampp
# mysql -u my_username -h %my_host% -p
Enter password: ********
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '%my_host%' (11001)`

Comment: I got it to work! I was suing the ad hoc version, but I needed to set it permanently and then I had to restart the xampp application so I think you should change your answer to use `setx h1 "verylonghostname.1242354.com"`. That's what I had to do to get it to work. Thanks for the answer by the way. It got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `.my.cnf` in your home directory. Put:

```
[client_h1]
host=host name 1
user=username 1
database=db 1

[client_h2]
host=host name 2
user=username 2
database=db 2
```

Then you can use:

```sh
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=_h1 -p
```

to get the defaults from the `[client_h1]` group, and

```sh
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=_h2 -p
```

to get the defaults from the `[client_h2]` group.

If you have any defaults that are the same for both servers, you can put them together in a single `[client]` group instead of repeating them in each group.